# Functions and strings

Tags: c, string, function, void

im very new to programming, trying to learn C and cant figure out how to create/use a simple function.

Im trying to create a function called stringtest and then call it into the main and simply make the string strA print ABC.

```
void stringtest(char strA[20])
{
    strA = "ABC";
}

int main()
{
    char strA;
    stringtest(strA[20]);
    printf("This is strA", strA);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I will explain all the UBs.. there are 2 places where they sneak in. BTW did you compile?

Comment: If you're writing code like this you need a significantly better book or reference on the C programming language. C is a very unforgiving language, so don't think you can just have at it and figure it out.

Comment: Compile the code first.

Comment: Surely it won't compile. I second the book suggestion.

Comment: oh it wont compile, thats what im trying to figure out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read up on pointers and the C syntax in general.

This is one way you could do it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void stringtest(char *strA) {
    strcpy(strA, "ABC");
}
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    char strA[20];
    stringtest(&strA[0]);
    printf("This is strA -> %s \n", strA);
    return 0;
}
```

Take care,

/Anders.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your code ran!! 
There are a lot of bugs and errors in your code.
See the code given below to understand how to do this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
char strA[20];

void stringtest(){
    strA[0]='A';
    strA[1]='B';
    strA[2]='C';
    strA[3]='\0';
}

int main(){

    stringtest();
    printf("This is strA %s",strA);

}
```

Comment: Please don't use a global variable

Comment: You say there is a lot of bugs without explaining any of them.

Comment: 1. we can't use `strA="ABC"` in C 

2. you are trying to print strA using printf without using %s specifier

3. strA is declared as a char , not as an array of character